# Producing a map for each location row using ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- read.csv(text = "name,lat,long
Tom,42,-73
Sally,41,-72
Harry,41,-74")
```

That has the lat long of 3 people.  Using ggmap I'd like to produce a map per row, in this case to show the location of each of the three people.

I've used ggmap before, but my go-to code of:

```
ggmap(get_map(location = c(lon = lon, lat = lat, 
                           zoom = 12, color = "bw", source = "osm"))) +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=longitude,y=latitude), color='red')
```

...doesn't work event to pull the map and centre it. I'd like to first centre the map on the person's location, then drop the point at that central location, with three maps as the output.

Thanks.

Comment: For each of these three maps, do you want the other two points to be on the same map?

Comment: No, I'd like to produce one map per row of data, with one point per map, the map centered on that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the data frame to produce one map per row:

```
library(ggmap)

p <- vector("list", 3)

for (i in seq_along(df)){
  p[[i]] <- ggmap(get_map(location = c(lon = df$lon[i], lat = df$lat[i]), 
                     zoom = 12, color = "bw", source = "google")) +
    geom_point(data=df[i,], aes(x=long, y=lat), color='red')
}

> p[[1]]
```

[image: plot1]

```
> p[[2]]
```

[image: plot2]

```
> p[[3]]
```

[image: plot3]

Notes:

1. You had `zoom = 12, ... source = "osm"` *inside* the `location = c(...)` argument. These should be arguments for `get_map()`.
2. For some reason I got an error with openstreetmap (HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'), so I used the default google maps instead.

Comment: I think there has been issues in downloading osm. For example, [this](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/172) has been reported.

Comment: @Z.Lin - Your code works great for the example data, but I've tried to use with 4 locations and updated the first line to:
    p <- vector("list", 4)
but the loop only produces 3 maps. Any ideas?

Comment: @nycrefugee The loop goes through each row of the data frame (`seq_along(df)`), so I'd first check how the 4th location was added to the data frame. Is it in a 4th row?

Comment: @Z.Lin yes, I added another row into the reproducible data above and load in though a code snippet in an Rmd document. I changed the vector to 4, but it never makes it past 3 rounds of the loop. I tried saving out df and re-loading, but to no avail.  I'll keep trying - thanks.

Comment: @nycrefugee Try setting `i = 4` explicitly & run the code inside the loop to see what's going on

Comment: @Z.Lin - tried that. It's bizarre. I've placed `i=4` inside, outside, inside and outside and it still gives up after three maps.

Comment: `ggmap(get_map(location = c(lon = df$lon[4], lat = df$lat[4]), zoom = 12, color = "bw", source = "google")) + geom_point(data=df[4,], aes(x=long, y=lat), color='red')` returns nothing?

Comment: @Z.Lin there must have been some system error because the original code now works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map(function(x, y, z) {
  ggmap(get_map(location = c(lon = x, lat = y), 
                zoom = 12, color = "bw", source = "google")) +
    geom_point(data = df[z,], aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "red")
}, df$long, df$lat, seq_along(df))
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This works for the three data points in the test frame above. However, if for this solution, any two points are within the same field of view, they appear together.  This doesn't happen with the solution from @Z.Lin below.

Comment: @nycrefugee You're right. I've edited my answer so it works even if any other points are in the same field of view.